# Close button closes application behind the actual one. What is the problem?

Tags: unity, windows, window-buttons

Occasionally when I hit the close button ('x' on the left) instead of closing the application I am looking at, it closes another application. A very common example situation:

I am using Firefox, and then I open the Trash directory. Then I click in the close button and the trash do not go away, but Firefox does.

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

that happen to me, too (expecially with Eye of GNOME Image Viewer).

Workaround:
first clik on the window you want active, then close it.

or

compiz-config → accessibility → opacify:

If the active windows is different respect the one you are looking, you see it also if it look like to be in the bottom (so, if you close, you know you are closing the one you see better).

Not a perfect english... but I hope you understood.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me as well, but I tend to blame my slow laptop. Because of this, I use Ctrl+W shortcut most of time to close window or Ctrl+Q to quit program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever used the X button in the corner. I usually head to the launcher, right click my current application, and quit.